# Display SharePoint 2013 document library (App) as IFRAME

Tags: document-library, app, iframe

Can I display a standard document library (SharePoint 2013) as an IFrame on external web page?

If yes, whats the easiest way of accomplishs this?

Comment: with external do you mean out of the SharePoint site collection or site?

Comment: Sorry, with external I mean an non-SharePoint page i.e a different application.